# Eclipse 4 Application RCP and a REST API

Tags: eclipse, api, rest, treeview, rcp

I'm developping an **Eclipse RCP Application** that have to display in a **Treeview** the collections of a **DataBase**.

The collections of the **DataBase** are provided by a **REST API**.

So, what i have to do is to call the **REST API** by given the **URL** and the **KEY** and display result (**The collections)** in the **Treeview**.

What i know about **REST API** is that it's used (most of the time) in web applications, but it's not the case for me.

Does anybody know how to call a **REST API** from an **Eclipse RCP Application** ?
Does someone have an experience with **RCP** and **REST API** ?

Thanks in advance.

Ismail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the RestAPi, i've used the **SpringFramework** using this :

**org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate** and its methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use whatever java rest client you want. I personnaly preferred using jersey because sometimes using Spring Framework inside Eclipse can be painful.

It worked for me adding all these librairies :

```
 lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar,
 lib/jersey-client-1.19.jar,
 lib/jersey-core-1.19.jar,
 lib/jersey-json-1.19.jar,
 lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar,
 lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar,
 lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar,
 lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar,
 lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar,
 lib/jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
```

And a simple call is as follow :

```
try {
            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

            WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/getMyObject");
            ClientResponse response = webResource.get(ClientResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
            }

            MyObject output = response.getEntity(MyObject.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            //Handling errors

        }
```

JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING is for the auto mapping to json using jersey-json and jackson-*.jar